# Visual studio not generate DLL during compile website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dll, compilation

When I try to compile my website in visual studio 2015 or visual studio 2017, it says that compile was successful but it doesn't generate any DLL in and all the code-behind files compiled to the target folder.

May you please help me how to resolve the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the website in order to get dll.In publish window select file system in Connection